# Install the Radrails plugin for Aptana Studio offline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, radrails

I downloaded and installed the Aptana Studio free version. But apparently, to install the Radrails plugin for ruby on rails development you have to connect to the internet. I don't have internet on my machine right now. So is there a way I could download the installer from another machine and copy it over my existing Aptana installation?

Update: Found a link for download [here](http://update.aptana.com/install/rails/3.2/) (Access denied now)

Comment: FWIW, the link in your "Update" is now "Access Denied".  Why can't they just make it easy to find offline install files?  It's enough to make me want to just ditch Aptana altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote down [my duel with Aptana Rails](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2008/02/showmethemoney-15-aptana-radrails-hell.html) - See if this helps you.
There is a link on manual installation that may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to actually install it on the machine with the Internet connection, then you can simply copy over the directory you installed it in. Eclipse installations are completely self-contained in their installation directories.